# Android Studio Bumblebee

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I was using Android Studio Arctic Fox and was having few problems.

Stupidly, I responded to the constant prompting to upgrade to Bumblebee and now I have no Android emulator.

The button on the toolbar does nothing and there is no emulator option in the view-Tool Windows tab.

I definitely have the emulator installed. I even deleted and reinstalled it in case something had become corrupted in the update.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Update: I rolled back to Arctic Fox and the emulator works perfectly. However, none of the plugins will work with Arctic Fox now so that's not an option.

Comment: Yea same here, upgraded to Bumblebee and emulator does not even work. Sucks that android team rolled out an update that does not even work.

Comment: I've gone back to Arctic Fox and am having no problems with the emulator. I'd recommend that for now.

Comment: Same here!! This is not good...the only solution is to double click the shift and search Virtual Device Manager